# For which positive integers $n$ we can group all divisors of $30^n$ as triplets with equal product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The problem is

> to find all such positive integers $n$ that we can group all divisors of the number $30^n$ as triplets with equal product.

A divisor of $30^n$ has a form $2^i3^j5^k$ with $0\leq i,j,k\leq n$. I figured that in order to solve this problem we can first solve the following:

> For which positive integers $n$ we can group all integers form $1$ to $n$ as triplets with equal sum?

All I could do so far is reformulate. Let's consider a set of all positive integers up to $n$:
$$K_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
For which $n\in3\mathbb{Z}_+$ we can decompose $K_n$ as
$$
K_n=K_n^1\ \sqcup \ \ldots\ \sqcup \ K_n^{n/3}
$$
where $|K_n^i|=3$ and $\sum \{x\in K_n^i\}=n(n+1)/6$. But I'm not sure this can be of any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "group as triples with equal product?", can you give an example to elaborate?

Comment: Have you looked for examples?  Well $p^2$ works, as there are only three divisors.  What about $30^1$ or $30^2$....

Comment: Note:  you need the number of divisors to be divisible by $3$.  That gives you some cheap information on $n$.

Comment: @lulu, the number of divisors of $30^n$ is $(n+1)^3$ so that means that $n+1$ is divisible by 3

Comment: Yes, and a little more work also shows what the common product of all your triples would have to be.  So, searching for examples means looking at $30^2,30^5, 30^8, \cdots$.  What happens there?

Comment: @lulu, okey, the product of all divisors is $M=30^{(n+1)^2n/2}$, so the common product of all triples is $M^{1/3}=30^{(n+1)^2n/6}$

Comment: Right, so for $n=2$ we are looking at $2^33^35^3$.  Seems suggestive.

Comment: Hold on...maybe I agreed too quickly.  I get $M=30^{(n+1)^3/2}$.

Comment: For $n=1$ it's pretty easy to see that $M=810000$ which matches my formula.

Comment: I think $\sum K^i_n=\sum K_n/(n/3)=3(n+1)/2$, not $n(n+1)/6$.

Comment: Then $n=6k+3$ and we can find  the following partitions for small $k$: $123$; $159,267,348$,...